# UINavigationItem not displaying left and right barButtons

Tags: ios, swift

I'm testing my app on an iPhone 6+. I have a navigation bar which includes two labels, a left bar button (not shown initially), and a right bar button. The problem is that the labels are shown but no matter how hard I try I can't make it show the buttons. They work(if you tap on where they should be, they work as expected) but are not shown. The tests on an iPhone 5s (physic) and iPhone X (simulator) went correctly and the buttons are shown.

Is there any problem with my code?

Thank you.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView.delegate = self
    loadWeb()

            let button = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.action, target: self, action: #selector(share))
    button.tintColor = UIColor.white
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button


    let frameLabelURLTitle = CGRect.init(x: 25, y: 2, width: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.width)! - 182, height: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height)! - 20)
    let frameLabelURL = CGRect.init(x: 25, y: 2 + frameLabelURLTitle.height, width: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.width)! - 182, height: 10)
    let viewLabel = UIView.init(frame: frameLabelURLTitle)
    labelTitleURL = UILabel.init(frame: frameLabelURLTitle)
    labelURL = UILabel.init(frame: frameLabelURL)
    labelURL.textColor = UIColor.white
    labelTitleURL.textColor = UIColor.white
    labelURL.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13.0)
    viewLabel.addSubview(labelTitleURL)
    viewLabel.addSubview(labelURL)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(viewLabel)

    loadingLabel.text = "loadingWeb".localized()
    loadingLabel.sizeToFit()
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true

    self.placeHolderView.layer.insertSublayer(initGradient(bounds: self.view.bounds, isHorizontal: false), at: 0)
    self.loadingGifImageView.image = UIImage.gif(asset: "01-GIF_LOGO")

}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    self.placeHolderView.isHidden = true
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false

    labelTitleURL.text = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.title")
    labelURL.text = webView.request?.url?.absoluteString.components(separatedBy: "/")[2]

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil

    if !(webView.request?.url?.absoluteString.contains("/blog/"))! {
        let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "bt_close")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(back))
        newBackButton.isEnabled = true
        print(newBackButton.style)
        self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(newBackButton, animated: true)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = newBackButton
    }
}
```

Comment: `self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true`

Comment: you hide navigation bar you shouldn see nothing  , just set to `false`

Comment: Yes, initially I hide it because there is a placeholder view to load the website, when it is loaded, I unhide it.

Comment: Yes i notice that

Comment: if !(webView.request?.url?.absoluteString.contains("/blog/"))! {

Comment: Are you check this condition

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what do you mean? Has the condition anything to do with, e. g. the right button? It should always be displayed..

Comment: sorry you say that  this button work but not shown